Freewheel removal
I have a Gary fisher Bike and I want to remove the freewheel. I bought a freewheel remover tool that has 12 teeth and is compatible with my bike, however when I turn it counter clock wise it just gives me that clicking sound like when you're riding a bike and you don’t pedal. Then I turn it clockwise and I get one little click. No matter how much I turn it clockwise or counter clockwise, the freewheel is still attached to the back tire. How do I remove it?

You are slightly mixing up the terms. Your bike does not have a classic freewheel, but a freehub and a cassette. The freehub body and the hub itself together form the coasting mechanism. The cassette consists of the cogs but has no moving parts, and is mounted to the freehub body. You replace the cassette when it is worn.
To install a cassette on the freehub body, you just turn the removal tool clockwise, and the coasting mechanism will engage so it tightens fine. But to remove the cassette, you need to hold the cassette in place using a chain whip tool, like e.g. the Park Tool SR-12.2:

Don't try to hold the cassette with your hands, as you need a lot of force. Watch an instructional video auch as this one to see how it's done. Be careful not to hit your hands on the cogs.
